# Loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

Ok so I have a problem here that a group of us cannot seem to figure out, and it involves looping with javascript, but the code isn't exactly the problem, its the logic we cannot figure out, I could probably write the code if I knew the logic, so here it is:

A city has a population of 1000. A monster comes into the city, and initially can only consume people at a rate of 1 person/hour. Each time it digests someone, it adds to its consumption rate by 1 person per hour.

Write a loop that calculates how long it takes to finish off the 1000 people.

Here is the code we came up with, that gives us an answer of 46 hours.

```
var people = 0;
var hour = 0;
var rate = 0;

while (people < 1000) {
people = people + rate;
rate++;
hour++;
}
```

**The catch here is that we have already been told this is wrong, and the correct answer is 7.5 hours.** But we cannot figure out how this code would look like.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: I was about to do your homework, but the monster story scared me too much

Comment: Well the first obvious flaw is that this code starts with the monster eating 0 people during the first hour.

Comment: Is it every time it eats any number of people, or for each person it eats that it increases its appetite?

Comment: The other obvious flaw is that each hour it increases its rate by 1, where it should be increasing by the number of people consumed. Another obvious flaw is that this can't get the correct answer, since it counts up in integral hours, and as you know the correct answer is not an integral quantity of hours.

Comment: each person it eats, it increases its consumption rate by 1 person/hour, i know its becomes exponential, i just cannot figure out the logic behind it

Comment: @Brandon If the monster consumes n people in an hour, how much does its rate go up in that hour?

Comment: then it will increase by n people/hour. if it eats 10 people in an hour, its hourly consumption rate will increase by 10

Comment: So instead of increasing the rate by 1 each hour like in your code you should increase it by...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var time = 60;  // 60 minutes
var people = 0; // number of people eaten
var total_time = 0; // in minutes
while (people < 1000) {
    total_time += time;
    people += 1;
    time = 60 / (people + 1);
}
console.log(total_time / 60); // 7.4854..
```

I calculate how long it takes to eat the next person (`60 / (people + 1)` minutes) and eat one person at a time until I've eaten 1000 people.

Om nom nom nom.

Comment: @Halcyon, even though you have just been tricked into doing somebody's homework, I am glad you did. I liked reading this post, +1 for you!

Comment: I like a challenge as much as the next person ;)